# Erro em VBA ao deletar aba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Meus caros bom dia!

Preciso da ajuda de vocês com o código abaixo.

```
Sub atualizar()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Reembolso").Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Modelo").Copy after:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Sheets("Modelo (2)").Name = "Reembolso"

End Sub
```

Quando chega na linha "Sheets("Reembolso").Delete" o mesmo apresenta o erro "Não é possível inserir o modo de interrupção neste momento" e para.

Já tentei inserir o comando "On error" e nada adiantou.
Rodei a parte debaixo do código e depurou certo.

Essa planilha tem algumas outras abas que ficam ocultas, fiz o teste uma planilha a parte apenas com duas abas e rodou.

Alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errando?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver, a aba em questão estava usando dois botões do ActiveX, coloquei como itens normais e mudei para atribuir macro. Agora está tudo rodando.